# Why doesn't a link open up in a pop up webview?

Tags: android, webview

There is a website that I use which opens up in a new window on a desktop, now what I want to do is replicate that in an app. The code I have so far includes the setsupportformultiplewindows but when I click the link that opens the new window, nothing happens. my code for the browser is as follows

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView = null;
private EditText mInputUrl = null;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String thesite = intent.getStringExtra(MainPage.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

mInputUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_url);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String baseurl = "http://";
          String url = baseurl + mInputUrl.getText().toString();
          mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.loadUrl(thesite);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

final Activity MyActivity = this;
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
     }
```

There is further code below but not related to my issue

EDIT:

Here is an image which shows how I would ideally like it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwllmjebtw13rzw/webview.png

Comment: Which one of the Url loads ?? mwebView.loadurl(theSite) or  mWebView.loadUrl(url) ??

Comment: the default view is  mwebView.loadurl(theSite), mWebView.loadUrl(url) that is for an address bar I have

Comment: Does that load properly?

Comment: It does in the webview, but when I click a link that is meant to open a new window, nothing happens, apologies if that wasn't clear in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


            Intent webIntent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this,
                    NewWebViewActivity.class);
            webIntent .putExtra("urlparam", url);
            startActivity(webIntent);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

In shouldOverrideUrlLoading(),you can check the url and open it in another activity using startActivity().

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would that give something like this? [https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwllmjebtw13rzw/webview.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwllmjebtw13rzw/webview.png)

Comment: This will open the url in new activity which will have webview.

Comment: do you know of a way of doing it like the picture I have attached?